# How to change X Y cordinates depending on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have put small image(x=50, y=50, height=100, width=100) on HTML canvas with particular(fix) X, Y coordinates, height, width of image. 
I am getting X, Y coordinates when I click on that image during normal browser window. But I am not getting proper X, Y coordinates on click on that image  when I resize the browser window. why ?

```
<canvas  id="myCanvas"  height="720" width="1280"></canvas>
```

// getting x y of window when i click on canvas

```
    var canvasnew = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var rect = canvasnew.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    var mouseX=event.pageX - rect.left; // get X of canvas
    var mouseY=event.pageY - 14;// get Y of canvas
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    //alert("windowHeight = "+ windowHeight +" , windowWidth = "+ windowWidth ); // window height, width
    var heightRatio = 720/windowHeight;
    var widthRatio = 1280/windowWidth;
    mouseX=mouseX*widthRatio;
    mouseY=mouseY*heightRatio;
    //alert("X= " + mouseX +" , Y= "+ mouseY); // x y coordinates on mouse click

if((mouseX>=x) && (mouseX<=Number(x)+Number(w)) && (mouseY>=y) && (mouseY<=Number(y)+Number(h)))
{
    alert(" clicked on image");
}
```

// image draw on canvas using following code

```
imageobj[d] = new Image();  
(function(d)
{
imageobj[d].src = sitePath+"foldername/image.png"; // image path
imageobj[d].onload = function()
{
ctxupdate.drawImage(imageobj[d], 50, 50,100, 100);
};
})(d);
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pwszc9hb/

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to pint-point the problem with the code that you have shared.

On possible solution:

What if you simply use this to get the mouse position:

```
var mouseX = event.pageX - canvasnew.offsetLeft,
var mouseY = event.pageY - canvasnew.offsetTop;
```

It should work also if you zoom your browser window.